# Opencv C++ Opens Two Window for Each imshow

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am using OpenCV 3.3.0 for c++ in visual studio. The problem is that when I use this code, it opens two windows with the same name that one of them contains the image and the another one is extra and empty. ([Screenshot from the two windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAseB.jpg) )

```
cv::Mat im0 = cv::imread("C:\\Users\\MY_PC\\Desktop\\Image.bmp"); //read the image
cv::resize(im0, I, cv::Size(640, 480), 0, 0, CV_INTER_LINEAR); //Resize the image to 640x480


cv::namedWindow("HI");
cv::imshow("HI", I);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

The more important problem following this problem, is that the `waitkey()` function just works with the extra window and I should press the keys on that window to see the changes in the another window.

Furthermore the `setMouseCallback` has the same problem and mouse commands doesn't work on the window containing the image. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't see any mistakes, however, I'm usually writing like that:
 const char* display_name = "Display";//Display name
        namedWindow(display_name, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);//Create Display

Comment: I got a similar issue on 3.4.0 version x64

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with the project type "Win32 Console Application".
If you use a "Empty Project" the problem disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the line `cv::namedWindow("HI");`, does it work?

Unfortunately I can't help with other two.

Comment: No, the "imshow" does't work without "namedWindow" (Exceptional Error happens).

Comment: @Peyman I just checked my code where I don't have such problem, try `cv::namedWindow("HI", 1);`. How about now? If it works, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Do you mean "WINDOW_AUTOSIZE"? No, unfortunately it has no effect on my issue. I think the problem is related to opencv library or visual studio settings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any mistakes in the code you shared.
However, I'm usually writing like that:

```
const char* display_name = "Display";//Display name
namedWindow(display_name, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);//Create Display
imshow(display_name, frame);//Display Image
waitKey(0);//Wait a key to be pressed
```

Answer (score -1):

For x64: Removed opencv_world410.lib and just add opencv_world410d.lib from Additional Dependencies
(Common properties->Linker->Inputs->Additional Dependencies)

This link helps you to create config files for all of your projects:
https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/dd/d6e/tutorial_windows_visual_studio_opencv.html